# Synology DS2415+ no ssh logs

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, network-attached-storage, synology

as the title says, my synology sshd service appears to not be producing any ssh logs.

I've tried this guide: https://sites.google.com/site/benbriedis/ssh-on-synology without success.

I need the logs to debug this error message I get from my client when trying to create an ssh tunnel:

```
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
```

If anyone knows how to deal with either of the issues I would be grateful.